# Change in Standard on Metal Frames for screens

Tags: windows, screens

I replaced all my windows/screens back in 2006 after Hurricane Katrina. I am in the process of replacing some of screen but have run into a problem. Several of the corner connections broke when disassembling 3 screens. It seems that none of the corner connections sold at Lowes/Home Depot or on Amazon fit the metal frames from 2006. The placement of the spline channel is in the middle of the frame bar instead of at on side.

[image]

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer forum, not a general discussion board. What's your question? "If it's where do I buy this?" that's a shopping question that's off topic...